# Context for product search in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, firebase-realtime-database

I want to search for products in my app by their categories, retrieving data from firebase database. The search works but doesn't display the products and I can't figure out what other context is to be passed. I'm new to Django so any help would be appreciated.

here's my Welcome.html:

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="get" action="/postsign" id="s">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" value="{{ category }}" placeholder="Search by category" aria-label="Search" name="Search">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" onclick="location.href='/postsign/?category={{ category }}'" form="s">Search</button>
</form>
</div>
</nav>




 <div class="container">

      <div class="col-md-4">

          <div class="cards">
            {% for product in category %}


             <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">


                 <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ product.image }}" alt="Card image cap">
                 <div class="card-body">
                     <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.pname }}</h5>
                     <p class="price">{{ product.price }}</p>
                     <p class="card-text">{{ product.description }}</p>
                     <button class="btn btn-primary cart">Add to cart</button>
                     <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='{% url 'productView' %}'">View product</button>
                 </div>

             </div>


            {% endfor %}
          </div>
          </div>

      </div>
```

Here's the views:

```
def postsign(request):
 if request.method == 'GET' and 'csrfmiddlewaretoken' in request.GET:

   search = request.GET.get('Search')
   search = search.lower()
   timestamps = database.child("Products").shallow().get().val()



   pcategory = []
   for i in timestamps:
       category = database.child("Products").child(i).child("category").get().val()
       category = str(category)+"$"+str(i)
       pcategory.append(category)
   matching =[str(string) for string in pcategory if search in string.lower()]


   s_category = []
   s_id = [] 

   for i in matching:
      category,ids=i.split("$")
      s_category.append(category)
      s_id.append(ids)
   data = services.get_products()
   return render(request, "Welcome.html",{'category':s_category})
```

Here's how my database looks:

```
products{
  timestamp{
    name:...
    category:...
    }
  timestamp{
   name:..
   category:...
```

...

Comment: change `data` in template to `category`

Comment: @Abhyudai edited, thanks. But still cant retrieve other information like the images,description etc. Could you help with that?

Comment: did you change the line `{% for product in data %}` to `{% for product in category %}` inside your template ?

Comment: @Abhyudai yes I did

Comment: what change did you see? Try to print `s_category` inside your views, does the object have the required attributes?

Comment: @Abhyudai I tried searching for products under the category 'vehicle' and this is what's printed - ['Vehicle', 'Vehicle'] since I have two products in under vehicle in my database. But I'm trying to display the image, product name as well, in my templates but I'm not getting that

Comment: this means that your views doesn't return the required attributes. What is `string`? It isn't defined inside the code that you show.

Comment: @Abhyudai 'data' contains all the required attributes but passing that as a context doesn't work

Comment: then you should send `data` to the tempate in place of `s_category`